# How to add extension to selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, chrome-options

I've been trying to add an extension called [Surfe](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/surfe/kojhcdejfimplnokhhhekhiapceggamn). I downloaded the extension file and compressed it as a zip file(also tried it as crx file) but I kept getting this error. **selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: cannot process extension #1
from unknown error: cannot read manifest**.
This is my code:

```
extension_path = '/Users/t/Desktop/surfe.zip'


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_extension(extension_path)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the manifest file is present in the extension directory and that it is in the correct format. You could also try to add the `crx` file directly to the `ChromeOptions` object instead of a zip folder: